# How do I fix infinite printing of a webscraped value?

Tags: java, class, variables, web-scraping

Sorry if this is a newbie question. I am actually using this project to teach myself about Java. My program is essentially a web scraper that gathers and outputs many different metrics for a stock. The program was working fine until I realized that I needed to be able to call my variables across many other classes. After attempting to rewrite my code to achieve this, I noticed that the value would output an infinite number of times on the console. At first, I thought that this was because of my if else syntax, but that did not seem to be the case. Can someone please help me figure out how to only print the value once and ensure that it is usable across my other classes?

Here is my code:

```
package datacollection;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Tester
{

public static String fetchMarketCap()
{
    final String keyMetricsURL = "https://markets.businessinsider.com/stocks/ko-stock";

    // obtains the market cap value

    try {
        Document marketCapDocument = Jsoup.connect(keyMetricsURL).get();


        for (Element row : marketCapDocument.select("div.snapshot")) {
            if (row.select("div.snapshot__data-item:nth-of-type(3)").text().equals("")) {
                continue;
            }
            else
                {

                final String marketCapValue = row.select("div.snapshot__data-item:nth-of- 
type(3)").text();
                    System.out.println(marketCapValue.substring(0, 8));

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception marketCapDocumentException) {
        marketCapDocumentException.printStackTrace();

    }

    return fetchMarketCap();
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    //call your functions here. this is what the program scans for first and sees which classes and methods to call.
    System.out.println(fetchMarketCap());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the endless output is this line of code:

```java
    return fetchMarketCap();
```

It is called recursion.

If you want to reuse method fetchMarketCap() you may collect results in one String and return it to caller.

```java
public class Tester {

    public static String fetchMarketCap() {
        final String keyMetricsURL = "https://markets.businessinsider.com/stocks/ko-stock";
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            Document marketCapDocument = Jsoup.connect(keyMetricsURL).get();
            for (Element row : marketCapDocument.select("div.snapshot")) {
                if (row.select("div.snapshot__data-item:nth-of-type(3)").text().equals("")) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    final String marketCapValue = row.select("div.snapshot__data-item:nth-of-type(3)").text();
                    result.append(marketCapValue, 0, 8);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception marketCapDocumentException) {
            marketCapDocumentException.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //call your functions here. this is what the program scans for first and sees which classes and methods to call.
        System.out.println(fetchMarketCap());
    }
}
```